# Correct interpretation of an ODE solution

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I am not very good with Mathematica but I am trying to solve the following initial value problem

$y''(t)=\lambda_1 y'(t)e^{y(t)}+ \lambda_2 y'(t)e^{-y(t)},$

$ y(0)=0$

I have tried first the following generic expression

```
y[t_,  Lambda1_,  Lambda2_, c1_ , c2_] := 
 y[t] /. First @ 
     DSolve[   { 
       y''[t] == Lambda1 y'[t] Exp[y[t]] +  Lambda2  y'[
           t] Exp[-y[t]]  }   , y[t],t ] ] /. C[1] -> c1 /. C[2] -> c2
```

Giving

```
Log[(-c1 + 
  Sqrt[-c1^2 - 4 Lambda1 Lambda2
    Tan[1/2 (c2 Sqrt[-c1^2 - 4 Lambda1 Lambda2 + 
       t Sqrt[-c1^2 - 4Lambda1 Lambda2)])/(2 Lambda1)]
```

Which is always a complex number. Trying to insert the boundary condition leads to

```
 DSolve[   { 
  y''[t] == Lambda1 y'[t] Exp[y[t]] + Lambda2  y'[
      t] Exp[-y[t]], y[0] == 0  }   , y[t], t ]



   Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

   DSolve::bvfail: For some branches of the general solution, unable to solve the conditions.


   {}
```

Can anyone help me to interpret this equation, or the way I am possibly mishandling it?

Comment: I'm missing a second intial condition. What do you know about Lamda1, Lamda2?

Comment: lambda1 and lambda2 are just positive constants. Adding y`[0]=y0 does not change the picture above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this equation, I would operate a bit differently.

First, let us observe that the equation exhibits no explicit dependence on t. This allows us to easily decrease its order. Let us denote `y'[t]=u[y]`. In other words, we will consider the derivative, y'(t) as dependent only on y. Then dy'/dt=(du/dy)*(dy/dt). This yileds dy'/dt=u*u'. With this the equation is transformed to u*u'=(lambda1+lambda2)uexp(y). This one readily integrates yielding y'(t)=(lambda1+lambda2)exp(y)+c, where c is the constant of the first integration.

It makes sense to solve this one by `DSolve`:

```
DSolve[{y'[t] == lambda*Exp[y[t]] + c, y[0] == 0}, y, t]

(*  {{y -> Function[{t}, -Log[-(lambda/c) - 
       E^(-c t) (-1 - lambda/c)]]}}   *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks Alexei. Is this a general techinque? And the natural quesiton: how come Mathematica does not know about it (or, it gives an impossible answer)?

Comment: First question: If an ODE shows no explicit dependence on t, yes it is generally so. Second question: Mathematica knows a lot, but not everything. Sometimes one needs to help it.

Comment: A precisation. Under your transformation the equation actually becomes  u*u'=lambda1exp(y) - lambda2 exp(-y) + c(lambda,1, lambda2). Mathematica still seems to struggle with this: the generic form returns five distinct solutions all of which require lambda1lambda2 <0, but lambda1=lambda2=1 (sinh) returns an actual solution. I accept your answer as the mehtodologically correct though.

Comment: @Mr_3_7 In the equation you have written above there is no -y in the exponent. I solved what you gave.

Comment: The minus appears in the code but you are right, there is a typo in the tex. Edited.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch actually `DSolve` do use this exact technique. It get's tripped up applying the initial condition afterward.

Comment: @Chip Hurst That's right. My only point is that if something does not work by itself it is sometimes useful to apply a simplification (if you see one) and after that to go to Mma again.

Comment: After a few more attempts: Mathematica does solve correctly the equation once any specific lambda1 and lambda2 are assigned. However it does not seem to be able to handle correctly the generic case. Anyway, I ended up solving it on paper  using the degree reduction of Alexei

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution:

General solution:

```
dsol = First@ DSolve[{y''[t] == Lambda1 y'[t] Exp[y[t]] + Lambda2 y'[t] Exp[-y[t]]}, y, t]
(*
{y -> Function[{t}, 
   Log[(1/(2 Lambda1))(-C[1] + 
      Sqrt[-4 Lambda1 Lambda2 - C[1]^2] Tan[1/2 (t Sqrt[-4 Lambda1 Lambda2 - C[1]^2] + 
           Sqrt[-4 Lambda1 Lambda2 - C[1]^2] C[2])])]]}
*)
```

General initial conditions:

```
c2sol = First@Solve[y[0] == Log@c1 /. First@dsol, C[2]]
(*
{C[2] -> ConditionalExpression[(
   2 (ArcTan[(2 c1 Lambda1 + C[1])/Sqrt[-4 Lambda1 Lambda2 - C[1]^2]] + π C[3]))/
   Sqrt[-4 Lambda1 Lambda2 - C[1]^2], 
   C[3] ∈ Integers && -π < Im[Log[c1]] <= π]}
*)

c1sol = First@Solve[y'[0] == c2 /. dsol /. c2sol, C[1]]
(*
{C[1] -> ConditionalExpression[(c1 c2 - c1^2 Lambda1 + Lambda2)/c1, C[3] ∈ Integers]}
*)

ysol = y[t] /. dsol /. c2sol /. c1sol // 
  Simplify[#, C[3] ∈ Integers && Log@c1 ∈ Reals] &
(*
Log[(1/(2 c1 Lambda1))(-c1 c2 + c1^2 Lambda1 - Lambda2 + 
   c1 Sqrt[-4 Lambda1 Lambda2 - (c1 c2 - c1^2 Lambda1 + Lambda2)^2/c1^2]
     Tan[1/2 Sqrt[-4 Lambda1 Lambda2 - (c1 c2 - c1^2 Lambda1 + Lambda2)^2/c1^2] t + 
      ArcTan[(c1 c2 + c1^2 Lambda1 + Lambda2)/(
       c1 Sqrt[-4 Lambda1 Lambda2 - (c1 c2 - c1^2 Lambda1 + Lambda2)^2/c1^2])]])]
*)
```

Solution to OP's IVP:

```
yivp = ysol /. c1 -> 1
(*
Log[(1/(2 Lambda1))(-c2 + Lambda1 - Lambda2 + 
   Sqrt[-4 Lambda1 Lambda2 - (c2 - Lambda1 + Lambda2)^2]
     Tan[1/2 Sqrt[-4 Lambda1 Lambda2 - (c2 - Lambda1 + Lambda2)^2] t +
       ArcTan[(c2 + Lambda1 + Lambda2)/
       Sqrt[-4 Lambda1 Lambda2 - (c2 - Lambda1 + Lambda2)^2]]])]
*)
```

Check:

```
{y''[t] == Lambda1 y'[t] Exp[y[t]] + Lambda2 y'[t] Exp[-y[t]], 
   y[0] == 0} /. y -> Function @@ {t, yivp} // Simplify
(*  {True, True}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks! DSolve really needs some pre-processing I see

Comment: There is still something fishy with the way Mathematica does this though. Lambda1 and Lambda2 cannot be positive in this solution. However, when I plug in positive values right at the outset, I get a (different) solution without problem.